# Add a jQuery snippet for sepcific user role

Tags: jquery, admin, javascript, hooks

I want to add a little code snippet to the edit page if the current user is of a specific user role.

I do know how to check for the userrole in php, but I have no clue how to find out if the page is an edit post or edit pages page and how to add the snippet with php. Please note that jQuery must be available at this point.

I don't want to user `wp_enqueue_scripts` because it really only is a little snippet and I don't want to create a new file for this. The code should happily live inside my `functions.php`

### Edit

According to Greg McMullen's answer I wrote the following which works well.

```
function function_to_run() {
  if ($_GET['action'] != "edit"){
    return;
  }

  $user_roles = array('role1', 'role2');

  foreach ($user_roles as $user_role) {
    if( current_user_can($user_role) ) {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'pending_post', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script1.js' );
    }
    else {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'pending_post', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script2.js' );
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'function_to_run' );
```

However, I think that it's very dirty to include 2 different files that contain 2 lines of code each.

Even if it's not best practice, I would like to add the js code to the php file. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook to load your snippet on the edit page as seen in [this example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) from the codex

```
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    if ( 'edit.php' != $hook ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/myscript.js' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is there a possibility to NOT use `wp_enqueue_script`?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I cannot recommend it. Why wouldn't you want to use it? You should really separate form/function. And if it's a small file, does it really matter if it exists independently or not?

Comment: Well I have to alter the code depending on the current user role. If it's a specific one the first snipped should be added, if it's any other role, an other snipped should be added. I find that it's a dirty way to `wp_enqueue_script` two different files of 3 lines...